# Switch statement with multiple conditions on C#

Tags: c#

Could you tell me how to use `switch` with the below mentioned code snippet ?

```
if (IsSelectedOrganizer)
{
   //
}
else if (IsNewOrganizer && IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist)
{
  //
}
else if (IsNewOrganizer && !IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist)
{
    //
}
else
{
   //
}
```

But on `Javascript` we can do that as shown below.But `C#` it doesn't allow ? It says `A constant value is expected`

```
                  switch (true) {
                        case IsSelectedOrganizer:
                            //
                            break;
                        case IsNewOrganizer && IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist:
                            //
                            break;
                        case IsNewOrganizer && !IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist:
                            //
                            break;
                    }
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple `else if` for the same `IsNewOrganizer && IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist`?

Comment: Do you want to replace it with a SWITCH statement or use SWITCH statements within those if / elseif conditions ??

Comment: @SonerGönül sorry,Corrected that.

Comment: @AshutoshVyas I need to replace it with a SWITCH statement.

Comment: Perhaps store a property that uses these bools as binary flags, turning every unique combination of true/false values into a unique integer, and switch on that?

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? What do you hope to gain? It isn't really logic that is suitable to a switch

Comment: A `switch` case is suitable when you have one condition which may result in multiple different actions being taken. This isn't the case. Why do you think you need a `switch`?

Comment: There is no point replacing this with a switch. You would not gain any simplicity or performance.

Comment: @Sampath, why do you need to replace it with a `switch`? With three values under test, the short answer is "you can't"

Comment: Maybe first explain what you are functionally trying to achieve, because this does not make sense.

Comment: From a computer science point of view, the javascript snippet you shared is not considered good code.  Personally, while I can see *why* it works, it is certainly debatable whether it *should* work.  I would suggest avoiding that code practice entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a perfect use case for an `if` not for a `switch`, so i suggest to keep it. But you could improve it a little bit:

```
if (IsSelectedOrganizer)
{
    //
}
else if (IsNewOrganizer)
{
    if (IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist)
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}
else
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Your solution reduces 1 outer branch completely :)

Answer (score 4):

A `switch` statement cannot have multiple conditions in it like `if/else` does, this is because `switch` is typically implemented as a fast in-program hashtable which means that: 1) All comparison values must be const, and 2) it doesn't actually perform as many comparisons as there are switch case expressions.

There is a "workaround" that requires converting a boolean expression into a custom `enum` value and then `switching` on that, but I don't see how it would be of any help in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a great candidate for a switch statement as your logic depends on the values of several variable rather than checking a single variable for different values.

Here's an example of the sort of code that's easy to convert to a switch statement:

```
if (value == 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
else if (value == 1)
{
    // etc
}
```

As a switch statement that would be:

```
switch (value)
{
    case 0:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case 1:
        // etc
        break;
}
```

There's nothing wrong with using `if`...`else if` statements if you're checking combinations of different variables, as you are. If for some reason you have to use a switch statement, the best solution would be to create an `enum` with values representing each of your possible states, then switch on that. For example:

```
enum OrganizerType
{
    SelectedOrganizer,
    NewOrganizerUserExists,
    NewOrganizerUserDoesntExist
}

// ...

OrganizerType orgType = calculateOrgType();

switch (orgType)
{
    case SelectedOrganizer:
        // do stuff
        break;
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise purely is "can it be done?", here's a solution. No developer, ever, should consider using this in real life though:

```
var switchValue = IsSelectedOrganizer ? 4 : 0 +
                  IsNewOrganizer ? 2 : 0 +
                  IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist ? 1 : 0;

switch (switchValue)
{
    case 7:
    case 6:
    case 5:
    case 4:
        // IsSelectedOrganizer part
        break;
    case 3:
        // IsNewOrganizer && IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist part
        break;
    case 2:
        // IsNewOrganizer && !IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist part
        break;
    default:
        // else part
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int FlagValues
{
    return (IsSelectedOrganizer & 1) + (IsNewOrganizer & 2) + (IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExists & 4)
}

switch (FlagValues)
```

Comment: Would you really add another of level of indirection in your code just so you can `switch` on something that can't be switched on directly?

Comment: He doesn't want to obfuscate his code, I think it's better to keep it readable and simple :)

Comment: I'll leave that decision to @Sampath

Answer (score -1):

In no respect better than using `if`s but implemented using `switch`s ;-).

```
switch (IsSelectedOrganizer)
{
    case true:
    {
        //
    }
    break;
    default:
    {
        switch (IsNewOrganizer)
        {
            case true:
            {
                switch ((IsOrganizerUserAlreadyExist))
                {
                    case true:
                    {
                        //
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                    {
                        //  
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            break;
            default:
            {
                //
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```